# Magic Keyboard Number Keys 0 - 9 NOT Working

Tags: imac

The number keys 1 - 9 are not responding

0 and Enter do work

As a result I cannot enter the pairing code

( mouse keys are not enabled )

purchased off eBay and the magic keyboard came with it. I have plugged in a cheap standard USB keyboard and that works fine. It is the older magic keyboard so only has number keys at the top. Can I rest this keyboard somehow?

Please advise

Comment: Can you add some details please? Is this a new problem or has it been going on for some time? Is the keyboard fully charged? Do you have another keyboard you could try (to see whether it is a hardware or a software problem)? Does it only occur when entering the paring code or for any input? Are you talking about the number keys on top of the keyboard or the ones on the number pad on the right hand side?

Comment: I purchased an iMac off eBay and the magic keyboard came with it. I have plugged in a cheap standard USB keyboard and that works fine. It is the older magic keyboard so only has number keys at the top. Can I rest this keyboard somehow?

Comment: Also, when the iMac discovers the keyboard, it finds it as “Roberts keyboard” instead of “Apple magic keyboard” or whatever..

Comment: I tried leaving the batteries out overnight but just retried to pair and still it’s not working

Comment: Please edit the question with addition details. Keyboards can be renamed, so Robert is probably just the name of the previous owner.

Comment: Yea but how can I pair it?

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Prompts for pairing code on MacOS Big Sure, tapping 0, backspace, esc & Enter key work (as evidenced by movement onscreen), no other key combinations seem to work. Fresh batteries, various "hold down power key" tried. No success so far.  Worst is that I know this keyboard used to work (with a long-since-gone device). UK layout in case that matters.